Сильно лагает отрисовка canvas
Делаю flappybird через react, с использованием canvas. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что когда отрисовываю изображения труб, через которые должна лететь птичка, то со временем (примерно секунд через 30) все начинает лагать, мелькать и т.д.
const selector = useSelector(state => ({
        initBird: state.bird.initBird,
        initBoard: state.bird.initBoard,
        pipes: state.bird.pipes,

    }),shallowEqual);
    

    useEffect(() => {
        let canvas = document.querySelector('#game-board-flappy');
        dispatch(actions.initBoard(canvas.width,canvas.height));
        dispatch(actions.initBird(canvas.width/8,canvas.height/2));
        dispatch(actions.addPipe());
        let intervalId = setInterval(() => {
            dispatch(actions.addPipe()); //данная функция добавляет новые трубы (вернюю и нижнюю)
        }, 1500);

        return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
        
    },[])


    useEffect(() => {
        let canvas = document.querySelector('#game-board-flappy');
        let context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        function drawMovingObjects() {
            requestAnimationFrame(drawMovingObjects);
            drawBack(canvas,context);
            drawBird(canvas,context,selector.initBird);
            for (let elem of selector.pipes){
                elem.x -= 2;   
                drawPipe(canvas,context, elem.img, elem.x, elem.y, 64, 512);
            }
        }
        
        drawMovingObjects();
        requestAnimationFrame(drawMovingObjects);
        
    },[selector.initBoard,selector.pipes])


Для начала, вот тут return () => setInterval(intervalId); должен быть clearInterval Потом так же посмотрите, через ваши 30 секунд, какое количество элементов у вас в selector.pipes? Может стоит "дорисовывать", а не перерисовывать все заново?

я пробовал добавлять dispatch(actions.delPipe()), функцию которая удаляет первые верхнюю и нижнюю трубы, то есть в selector.pipes всегда находилось 2 элемента, верхняя и нижняя трубы и все равно были такие же лаги

Расставьте по всему коду console и смотрите, где что начинает расти и выполняться долго.

Советы: 1) рассмотреть вместо setInterval такую штуку как requestAnimationFrame. Это более правильное решение 2) применение реакта для данных вещей - самое ужасное, что можно было придумать. Он делался не для этого и использовать его так - неправильно.......  если нужно сделать игру на js и canvas, то стОит обратить внимание на специализированные движки под это дело. Например phaser или Three.js или Pixi.js   .
